# How to avoid #1217 foreign key error in phpMyAdmin when changing the engine of table from InnoDB to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

i have some database, that contents some tables, all of them are in InnoDB mode. And also i have phpMyAdmin, where i can manage databases/tables.

For example, i have a table called "cache" that is innodb and works fine. I run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE cache ENGINE=myisam;
```

And get the error:

```
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I googled and also tried to use:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE cache ENGINE=myisam;
```

But no luck, still the same error. What can i do to change the ingine?

Comment: You need to first drop any foreign keys in that table, or in other tables that reference your `cache` table.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why change from InnoDB to MyISAM? MyISAM is practically deprecated. It doesn't support ACID properties. It's slower than InnoDB in almost all cases. It's susceptible to corruption. It's ironic that your table name is `cache`, since MyISAM has no data cache (only index cache).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to drop the foreign key (in phpmyadmin), but get this: #1025 - Unable to rename './db/cache' to './db/#sql2-4d78-3' (error: -1)

Comment: I can't guess what you did to try to drop the foreign key. There are numerous answers on Stack Overflow about that error message, and usually it is caused by a malformed ALTER TABLE statement, for example trying to drop the foreign key constraint using the name of the column instead of the name of the constraint (these may be different). I suggest you search Stack Overflow for that error, and see what solutions are suggested.